# Pytorch how to calculate the gradient of the upper part of the network

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a simple network like conv→conv→linear
I only have the gradient of the linear layer
How can I calculate the gradient of the two conv layers

I wonder if it's possible without the use of loss or something like smashed data in split learning.

Answer (score 0):

From the PyTorch documentation:

> The graph is differentiated using the chain rule. If the tensor is non-scalar (i.e. its data has more than one element) and requires gradient, the function additionally requires specifying gradient. It should be a tensor of matching type and location, that contains the gradient of the differentiated function w.r.t. self.

Thus, you need to call backward() on the linear layer passing in the gradient you have:

```
linear_out = linear(conv(conv(x)))
linear_out.backward(linear_grads)
```

where linear_grads is the gradient of the linear layer you already have.

Comment: So does it mean I still need both the output and the gradient of one layer to backward ?

Comment: You need to at least compute the forward operations until the point where you already have the 'outputs' that you have the gradients for. If you have more questions, I think you'll need to post the code you have and make your question more clear, as I'm not 100% sure what you actually have and what you need.